# What Warlock subclass suits this concept the best?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, warlock

I have a basic concept of a Warlock and need a hand in choosing the subclass. It can be a homebrew subclass as long as it's not too OP.

The character I'm going to play has made a pact with a strange patron:
Her patron is stuck to her out of its own will. It's trying to help her by consuming bad emotions (sadness, anger, fear etc.) before she could feel them.
It's also showing her an illusion of a world that's perfect (?) (I'm still thinking about this one). The character has been living in a fey forest for a while.

By that means she's happy, cheerful and does not fear some obvious dangers (although I'm still thinking if fear is counted as a 'bad' emotion since it's basically a common sense).

Although when something really bad happens, the patron might not be able to consume so much emotions and the character might need to roll a Wisdom Save (or something else) or be overwhelmed by that emotion.

So, because of that I thought that maybe the Archfey patron could work although I'm not sure if it would've done something like that out of its own will.

Answer (score 12):

### Archfey absolutely works.

The fey are notorious in DnD for being mischievous illusionists. They're often immortal and enjoy messing with the short-lived races. An archfey can and would (and probably have) tricked mortals into one-sided contracts.

Comment: Not to mention that Archfey are very emotional, so the fact that the OP's patron is all about effectively manipulating emotions, that fits the Archfey theme too.